# Difference in SECONDS between Sys.time() and origin ("1970-01-01 00:00:00 GMT"). R

Tags: r, time

Can anyone help me to find the difference in seconds between two datetimes in R?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
> difftime(Sys.time(),as.POSIXct("1970-01-01 00:00:00 GMT"),units = "secs")
Time difference of 1508429337 secs
```

Or as d.b rightly pointed out, if you only want the difference with respect to the origin, `as.numeric(Sys.time())`

Comment: Consider marking this answer as accepted if this answers your question.

Comment: For origin, you should be able to do just `as.numeric(Sys.time())`

Comment: @d.b your solution is much more succinct than mine. I've added it to my answer.

Comment: Note that the two solutions are **not** equal. It seems to be locale dependent. I've just tested both and when I saw the difference tried `difftime(.) - as.numeric(.)` to get `Time difference of 3599.999 secs`.

Comment: @d.b OK, so now I get `Time difference of -0.001000166 secs`. Wrong way of expressing the base time zone, should be `UTC` not `GMT` anymore.